CLion vs Stm32CubeIDE build size
I'm working on an embedded project for STM32 Bluepill. I was using Stm32CubeIDE for development but I recently transitioned to CLion (Jetbrains) as I really like that IDE. However, I noticed there's a noticable size increase when building with CLion. My flash memory is almost at capacity at 63.8KB whereas when I build the same code in Stm32CubeIDE, the flash is only used up 48KB. The MCU has 64KB flash memory and I still need to add stuff so it seems if I continue using CLion, I'll be running out of flash memory very soon.
My question is; what might explain this discrepency? The cMakeLists.txt file is identical in both IDEs and in fact, as far as I can tell, everything else seems to be identical but clearly, there's a marked difference somewhere.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Did you check out code optimization in STM32CubeIDE?
("C/C++ Build" then "Settings" change the optimize settings)

CubeIDE by default passes the following options to gcc: -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections which will cause unused data and functions to be omitted. Perhaps CLion is not.

Hm. I did find some options for Stm32CubeIDE but not sure where to put them in Clion. Do they go in the CmakeLists.text add_compile_options section?
./Debug/makefile: arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "diab.elf" @"objects.list" $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) -mcpu=cortex-m3 -T"/Users/122992/STM32CubeIDE/workspace_1.9.0/diab/STM32F103C8TX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="diab.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static -u_printf_float --specs=nano.specs -mfloat-abi=soft -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
Thanks.

That looks like the invocation of the linker, and it already has -Wl,--gc-sections, which is good. You need to ensure that the invocation of the compiler for your .c files has -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections.

You can pass necessary compiler flags like -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections either through CMake options in CLion or by setting them in CMakeLists.txt
Here is the doc about it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html#compiler-flags
